# SIGABRT when selecting rows in TableViewController

Tags: swift, tableview, cells, sigabrt

I have a problem:
When I select the 2nd cell of my tableView, I get a SIGABRT. But when I select the first one, everything works just fine.
It must have to do with my TableViewController Class, because "SET ROWS IN SECTION" (from my print statement) will be printed 3 times, when I select the 2nd cell, but 3 * 4 = 12 times, when I select the first one...
Oh... and I get this error:

```
GONNA SET THE ROWS IN SECTION
2
SET SECTION 2 TO 1
GONNA SET THE ROWS IN SECTION
0
SET SECTION 0 TO 1
GONNA SET THE ROWS IN SECTION
1
SET SECTION 1 TO 3
2016-07-04 12:43:14.407 Sessions[1229:629535] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1822e6db0 0x18194bf80 0x1821c7098 0x187b7d5ac 0x187933f1c 0x18756d444 0x18752aff8 0x1878e4b88 0x187529fc4 0x187529d5c 0x187529b68 0x187794a20 0x18752fac8 0x18743fac8 0x187465350 0x18743ed40 0x182c18cc0 0x18743ebc4 0x18744c678 0x18763edbc 0x18743fac8 0x18743f7ac 0x18743ed40 0x182c18cc0 0x18743ebc4 0x18744c678 0x1876df8c0 0x1874535b4 0x18763e8d4 0x18775e334 0x18763e44c 0x1875f8818 0x187503e40 0x187503b1c 0x187503a84 0x1874401e4 0x184dd2994 0x184dcd5d0 0x184dcd490 0x184dccac0 0x184dcc820 0x1874365f8 0x18229c728 0x18229a4cc 0x18229a8fc 0x1821c4c50 0x183aac088 0x1874ae088 0x1000f8b54 0x181d628b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

"SET SECTION 2 TO 1" means, that section 2 has 1 cell...
This is my class:

```
import UIKit

class SessionsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let header = ["Mediatoren", "Medianden", "Konfliktverlauf"]
    var medianden: Array<String> = []
    var mediators: Array<String> = []

//  ----------------
//  MARK : IBACTIONS
//  ----------------

    (I just deleted these...)

//  ---------------------
//  MARK : OVERRIDE FUNCS
//  ---------------------

    override func viewDidLoad() {super.viewDidLoad() }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning(){ super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()}
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        print(sessions.workingOnSession)
        medianden.append((sessions.workingOnSession["Name1"] as? String)!)
        medianden.append((sessions.workingOnSession["Name2"] as? String)!)
        medianden.append((sessions.workingOnSession["Name3"] as? String)!)
        medianden.append((sessions.workingOnSession["Name4"] as? String)!)
        //print(medianden)
        for _ in 0...3 {
            if medianden.last == "" {
                medianden.removeLast()
            }
        }
        print(medianden)
        mediators.append((sessions.workingOnSession["MID"] as? String)!)
        mediators.append((sessions.workingOnSession["MID2"] as? String)!)
        //print(mediators)
        for _ in 0...1 {
            if mediators.last == "" {
                mediators.removeLast()
            }
        }
        print(mediators)
    }

//  ---------------------
//  MARK : FUNCS
//  ---------------------

    (Deleted these too...)

//  -----------------
//  MARK : TABLE VIEW
//  -----------------

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return self.header[section]
    }
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("SET ROWS IN SECTION")
        print(section)
        if section == 0 {
            print("SET SECTION 0 TO \(mediators.count)")
            return mediators.count
        } else if section == 1 {
            print("SET SECTION 1 TO \(medianden.count)")
            return medianden.count
        } else if section == 2 {
            print("SET SECTION 2 TO 1")
            return 1
        }
        return 0
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        print("MAKE MY CELLS...")
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = mediators[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            cell.textLabel!.text = medianden[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
            let textCell = FSTextViewTableViewCell()
            return textCell
            //textCell.textView.text = sessions.workingOnSession["Description"] as? String
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

thanks to everyone!!! :-) and sorry for my bad english...
Fabian

Comment: You are missing a `{` in your definition of `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. Copy-paste error?

Comment: jap.. im sorry. but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear.

```
uncaught exception 'NSRangeException',
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
```

So you have an array with elements [0..1] inclusive and you're accessing element [2]. There are only so many arrays in your program: `mediators`, `medianden`, `self.header`. Try doing some more debugging to see which one is at fault.

It seems like you are assuming that `mediators` has 2 elements and `mediaden` has 4, and this is hard-coded. It's better to not sprinkle these dependencies throughout the code; instead, set the size once, and make the remainder of the code work independently of the size (with for loops etc).

Comment: well thanks... I can´t see, why my arrays are hard-coded? `mediators`can only have 1 or 2 items, because I fetch the data from a database... Same for `medianden`, but with the difference that it only can have 1 to 4 items... I assume that there is something wrong with `medianden`...